# CVXOPT QP Solver: TypeError: 'A' must be a 'd' matrix with 1000 columns

Tags: python, svm, typeerror, cvxopt, quadratic-programming

I'm trying to use the CVXOPT qp solver to compute the Lagrange Multipliers for a Support Vector Machine

```
def svm(X, Y, c):
      m = len(X)
      P = matrix(np.dot(Y, Y.T) * np.dot(X, X.T))
      q = matrix(np.ones(m) * -1)
      g1 = np.asarray(np.diag(np.ones(m) * -1))
      g2 = np.asarray(np.diag(np.ones(m)))
      G = matrix(np.append(g1, g2, axis=0))
      h = matrix(np.append(np.zeros(m), (np.ones(m) * c), axis =0))
      A = np.reshape((Y.T), (1,m))
      b = matrix([0])

      print (A).shape

      A = matrix(A)

      sol = solvers.qp(P, q, G, h, A, b)
      print sol
```

Here `X` is a `1000 X 2` matrix and `Y` has the same number of labels. The solver throws the following error:
`$ python svm.py 
(1, 1000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "svm.py", line 35, in <module>
    svm(X, Y, 50)
  File "svm.py", line 29, in svm
    sol = solvers.qp(P, q, G, h, A, b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cvxopt/coneprog.py", line 4468, in qp
    return coneqp(P, q, G, h, None, A,  b, initvals, options = options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cvxopt/coneprog.py", line 1914, in coneqp
    %q.size[0])
TypeError: 'A' must be a 'd' matrix with 1000 columns`

I printed the shape of A and it's a `(1,1000)` matrix after reshaping from a vector. What exactly is causing this error?

Comment: Try to print A.typecode as well, is it 'd'?

Comment: If it's not, try to do A=A.astype(double) before cast it to a matrix.

Comment: That was it. Type was **'i'**. Added the tc variable in the `matrix(A, (1, m), 'd')` and it worked! If you want to add it as an answer, I can accept it!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your matrix elements have to be of the floating-point type as well. So the error is removed by using `A = A.astype('float')` to cast it.

Comment: you mean A=A.astype(**float**)

Answer (score 4):

i have try `A=A.astype(double)` to solve it, but it is invalid, since python doesn't know what double is or A has no method astype.

### therefore

via using 

`A = matrix(A, (1, m), 'd')`

could actually solve this problem!

Answer (score 3):

The error - `"TypeError: 'A' must be a 'd' matrix with 1000 columns:"` has two condition namely:

1. if the type code is not equal to '`d`'
2. if the  `A.size[1] != c.size[0]`.

Check for these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

To convert CVXOPT matrix items to floats:

```
A = A * 1.0
```